# Symfony 5 API populate related object entities

Tags: php, rest, symfony, api-platform.com

I am trying to create a simple web app using Symfony 5. I am using the [API](https://api-platform.com/).

Currently when calling some endpoint it only displays the IRI link to the related link:

[image]

I need instead to display the related entity object itself; if I get the `Item` endpoint the related entity `Program` should be returned this:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "program": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "First program"
    },
    "description": "fgdfg",
    "comment": "dfgdfg"
{
```

So, this is how the table looks:

[image]

I thought [setting up a subresource](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/subresources/) would be enough to get the object but it wasn't:

1. In the `InventoryItem` entity configured `@ApiSubresource` annotation of the `Program` property:

   ```
   /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Program::class, inversedBy="inventoryItems")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
    * @ApiSubresource
    */
   private $program;
   ```
2. In `resources.yaml` file I configured the subresource:

   ```yaml
   App\Entity\InventoryItem:
      properties:
          program:
              subresource:
                  resourceClass: 'App\Entity\Program'
                  collection: true
   ```

This still returns the IRI instead of the object, The only thing that has changed was that now I can access to the related entity for the current object in this URL: `http://localhost:8000/api/inventory_items/1/program.json`.

Any idea on how to return the related entity object itself instead of the IRI URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're searching to serialize your item. So I guess this is more a serialization problem than a sub-resource problem.
I think you should use [serialization group](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#using-serialization-groups) instead of SubResource.

**SOLUTION1** Serialize the embedding relation

The ["Embedding relation"](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#embedding-relations) provides an example with Book and Author.

```php
<?php
// api/src/Entity/Item.php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ApiResource(normalizationContext={"groups"={"item"}})
 */
class Item
{
    /**
     * @Groups({"item"})
     */
    public $description;

    /**
     * @Groups({"item"})
     */
    public $comment;

    /**
     * @Groups({"item"})
     */
    public $program;

    // ...
}

// api/src/Entity/Person.php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

/**
 * @ApiResource
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * ...
     * @Groups("item") <=== This is item, not program but you can have two groups
     */
    public $name;

    // ...
}
```

**SOLUTION2** Mix subresources and serialization groups

This example should work, but (if subresources are necessary) you can mixed [subresources and serializations](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/subresources/#using-serialization-groups) too, but in you case I guess that the first solution is the best.